# Angular Material 2 dynamic Theme colors

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

I need to build a form in my Angular 4 app that uses material2 and overwrite the chosen theme (I have imported one, deeppurple-amber, because without a theme some components do not load properly). I have seen I can define my own themes using a `scss` file but I need to overwrite the primary color to a one defined previously by the user, and stored in the local storage

So I have this in my components' ts:

```
export class MyFormComponent implements OnInit {
    ...
    myPrimaryColor: string
    ...

    ngOnInit(){
        ...
        this.myPrimaryColor = localStorage.getItem('primarycolor');
        ...
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can insert a material input and customize in the html file the primary color like this?

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let field of fields" [color]="#myPrimaryColor">
    <input matInput [placeholder]="field.text">
</mat-form-field>
```

I have searched material docs but not found any input nor formfield attribute to do so. How could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

The `color` option is not a CSS property - it is an Angular Material directive that accepts a `ThemePalette` which is either `'primary'`, `'accent'`, `'warn'` or `undefined`. These colors are tied to your application's theme. If you want to change the style of an individual component based on a user chosen value, you could do that with `ngStyle`:

```
<mat-form-field *ngFor="let field of fields" [ngStyle]="{'color': myPrimaryColor}">
    <input matInput [placeholder]="field.text">
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this makes the input font to myPrimaryColor, but the color of the underline and the placeholder once focused remains as the theme's primary color,. I would like to change the color of these elements. Thanks

Comment: Those are themed elements (obviously). The whole Angular Material theming architecture works the way it does because you're not _supposed_ to change colors of elements outside of theming (but we all find reasons to do it anyway). It can be done with classes applied to your own components that override default material style, but doing it for literally _any_ color as chosen by a user would be insanity. If you are giving users control over individual component color, you will find this difficult - limiting color choices might make it possible. Giving them theme options for the app is no problem.

Comment: It is a requirement for the app I'm working in to let the user choose his primary color, that would be applied to all the components that should use it (Inputs, buttons, headers, ...), not component to component. I don't know if this changes the approach. Thank you anyway for your help

Comment: Swapping themes is reasonably straightforward. If you give users a few theme options, that works. I'm not sure if there's a way to update a color 'variable' and have that work with theming. Plus, you have to also consider that just changing the primary color value will not always work. A very light primary color would require a 'dark' theme, whereas darker and more saturated colors would require a 'light' theme.